# how can I see the viewer from table1 package

Tags: viewer

I keep have errors on console, I want to see the results in viewer to see table for airquality.

my code:

library(table1)
table1(~ Ozone+Solar.R+Temp+Month2, data = airquality)
table1(~ Ozone+Solar.R+Temp|Month2, data = airquality)

> library(table1)
> table1(~ Ozone+Solar.R+Temp+Month2, data = airquality)
> Error in ifelse(x >= 10^digits & isFALSE(round.integers), formatC(round(x),  :
> could not find function "isFALSE"
> table1(~ Ozone+Solar.R+Temp|Month2, data = airquality)
> Error in ifelse(x >= 10^digits & isFALSE(round.integers), formatC(round(x),  :
> could not find function "isFALSE"

could you help me out?

Comment: Could you please add appropriate tags and provide what you are doing (code, console input, etc) to get that error, and what is the expected output?

Comment: library(table1)
table1(~ Ozone+Solar.R+Temp+Month2, data = airquality)
table1(~ Ozone+Solar.R+Temp|Month2, data = airquality)